# Could reside be used in the sense of a user having an account on a website?

Tags: word-choice

When a user creates (for example) a blog on a website, I am wondering about if a user (not the person behind the user) could be said "to reside" on the link of the Web page. For example, if a blog is at GitHub at the link /catcoin10, could it be said that the user catcoin10 resides at https://github.com/catcoin10 ?

Comment: Reside: (of things, qualities, etc.) to abide, lie, or be present habitually; exist or be inherent (usually followed by in). https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reside

Comment: Could you possibly clarify what you are asking?  user067531 offers a fair definition of 'reside', in which 'to be present habitually' looks a possibility for you.  There could be a sort of metaphorical sense in the idea that a blogger could 'reside' in her/his own blog.  So If you used it, I think you would be understood.  Whether your choice of metaphor would catch on with others is not something that can be predicted.

Comment: Reside at the URL of the blog

Comment: By asking “could it be said” I take you to be asking whether it is idiomatic to stretch the meaning of “reside” to encompass a reference to an online presence. My answer would be no.  It carries meaning (it’s vaguely understandable) but it is not familiar to me at all.

Comment: It's not an unlikely metaphorical usage, though I don't recall ever hearing someone use it.  Remember, about half of English is metaphor.

Comment: A synonym for "reside" is "live" as in "I live at number 45". It is very common in colloquial speech for this use to be extended to inanimate objects, for instance "My bike lives in the garden shed". Obviously the bike, being a machine, does not really "live" anywhere but everyone would understand this to mean "I keep my bike in the garden shed". Given this I would say that it would be permissible to say "Our blog resides at www.blogprovider.org" but I do think that it would seem pretentious.

Comment: I agree that it's reasonable to say that the blog resides on the website. It would not be common to say that the *user* resides there.